# Wrong release number for Debian "7" instead of 8 information

Tags: debian, debian-jessie

I upgraded to Jessie last recently and when doing a `lsb_release -a` it reports that the release is 7 (instead of 8) and codename Jessie.

[image]

I did an `update && upgrade && dist-upgrade` when all sources point to jessie but no updates are available.

Another server I recently upgraded reports release 8 and Codename Jessie.

How can I fix this wrong information reported inside Release number ?
Thanks

Comment: check /etc/debian_version

Comment: it reports 8.6 inside it.

Comment: and /etc/os-release?

Comment: it doens't exist

Comment: can you post your sources.list ?

Comment: Sure: https://gist.github.com/tristanbes/763dbcef22bbdde74dbec0ab687b169d

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the same problem.

The `7` come from `/etc/lsb-release` :

```
DISTRIB_ID=Debian
DISTRIB_RELEASE=7
DISTRIB_CODENAME=
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=
```

However, it seems `/etc/lsb-release` file does not exist anymore in any package, but it has been kept back (I did not find any reported bug about it).

So just removed it:

```
rm /etc/lsb-release
```

`lsb_release -a` will so use `/etc/os-release` instead, which contains the good informations.

Comment: In my case it was `/etc/lsb-release`

Comment: True, misspelled, fixed